# T480 20L5 running KDE Neon not being recognized by USB-C ThinkPad Dock

Tags: thinkpad, dock

Is it possible to get thinkpad USB-C docks to work with KDE Neon? I am not even getting a power signal.

I've got KDE Neon 5.17 running on Linux version 5.0.0-37-generic (buildd@lcy01-amd64-023) (gcc version 7.4.0 (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1)) #40~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Nov 14 12:06:39 UTC 2019 –

Comment: KDE Neon 5.17                                                                                                       Linux version 5.0.0-37-generic (buildd@lcy01-amd64-023) (gcc version 7.4.0 (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1)) #40~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Nov 14 12:06:39 UTC 2019

Comment: Is there some sort of patch for this?